# Adding loggin code to obtain_auth_token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST framework site, which uses the default `obtain_auth_token` in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
```

which works fine, but I also implemented logging for my site to know what is going on. Is there a way to add logging to `obtain_auth_token` to log that user X has tried to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overriding the `post` of `ObtainAuthToken` should work.

example:

```
class MyAuthTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # log
        return response

my_token_view = MyAuthTokenView.as_view()
```

and in urls:

`url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.my_token_view)`

Comment: It seems to work as far as the overriding works, but I get the error that `super` needs arguments.

Comment: Got it: `super(MyAuthToken, self).post(...)`.